# How to Set (TableView cellForRowAtIndexpath) activity in A Button?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios4

Hey Guys, please let me know how can I set this code action in to an UIButton action...
Here is the code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *myIdentiFier=@"myIdentiFier";

myCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentiFier];

if(!cell){
    //cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:myIdentiFier];
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"myCell" owner:self options:nil];
    for(id obj in nib){
        if([obj isKindOfClass:[myCell class]]){
            cell=(myCell *)obj;
            break;
        }
    }
}

NSDictionary *diction=(NSDictionary*)[content objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

cell.empID.text=[diction objectForKey:@"empid"];
cell.empName.text=[diction objectForKey:@"empname"];
cell.designation.text=[diction objectForKey:@"empdesignation"];
cell.teamName.text=[diction objectForKey:@"empteam"];

return  cell;

}
```

i want to set above action in my button..

```
- (IBAction)displayRecord:(id)sender {
}
```

please tell me ...

Comment: what actually you are looking for

Comment: @Bhupesh whatever my tableview method is doing i want that it should done by button action..

Comment: Do you want to add new cell in the table view? For that you need to insert new entry in your data source i.e `content` array in your case. Once that is done, call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Answer (score 0):

you can call

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

than cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: Please elaborate.. i din get

Comment: look at this example: http://www.aboveground.com/tutorials/adding-a-uitableview-to-a-custom-uiview

Answer (score 0):

simply u can do as follow

```
- (IBAction)displayRecord:(id)sender {
           [yourTablename reloadData];
}
```

Comment: check your tableView frame

Comment: Not displaying.. data which displaying disappearing after click.. :(

Comment: Uncomment this line    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:myIdentiFier];

Comment: do you add delegate and datasource ?

Comment: check this link  "http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Automatic-Cell-Loading-UITableView-iOs-50--1456.php"